# How to send data while routing from a div component to a new page in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a div component inside a route which is the default route. From this component onClick I want to send a JSON object to a new page. This will be a newly opened page. Right now I could not find any better alternative so I am sending the entire JSON object in the URL but I know this is not a proper way to do it. Here is how I am doing it. I am sending the JSON object data in the url and using redirect push to go to a new page './shopdetail':-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


class ShopsCatOptions extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={            
            shopd: this.props.shop.name,
            redirect:false,
            data:JSON.stringify(this.props.shop)

        };        
    }
    handleOnClick = () => {
      this.setState({
        redirect: true,
      });
    }


    render() {
        if (this.state.redirect) {

            return <Redirect push to={"./shopdetail/"+this.state.data}/>;
        }

        return(
            <div class="expndinnerm" onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
            {
                this.state.shopd        
            }
            </div>
        )
    }

}
export default ShopsCatOptions
```

What is a better way to send this data. Can we send it in a way similar to the way we pass props to inner components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      You can do something like this         
       <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/shopdetail',
            state: { referrer: this.state.data}
        }} />

       To access:

       this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.referrer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use props history to do the push:

```
this.props.history.push({
             pathname:"/shopdetail",
             state:{
                 key:"value"
              }
            });
```

The key value is whatever you'd like, in your case mostly the redirect boolean.

Inside your non class component you can access the state via:

```
this.props.shopdetail.state (just an example)
```